# PHP string comparison between two different types of encoding

Tags: php, unicode, decode, encode

I am attempting to match a string I know to a web page title in php.

I have the following string:

ℛobinhood

I have a page title that looks like this:

ℛobinhood

but is actually encoded like this if I look at the `<title>` element:

```
&#8475;obinhood
```

I'm not sure how to compare these two strings. How do I either convert the `&#8475;` to ℛ or the other way so that I can do a proper comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use htmlentites ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php ) to convert to the entity version.

Answer (score 1):

Use the multibyte string functions:

- mb_convert_encoding() to convert both versions to something sane (UTF8, internal encoding)
- mb_strstr() to do the comparison

mb_* will have an encoding for HTML entities and (most likely) whatever encoding your string is in.