# Compare same values stored with different encodings

Tags: php, mysql

This question is not a duplicate of [PHP string comparison between two different types of encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766893/php-string-comparison-between-two-different-types-of-encoding) because my question requires a SQL solution, not a PHP solution.

---

**Context** ► There's a museum with two databases with the same charset and collation (`engine=INNODB charset=utf8 collate=utf8_unicode_ci`) used by two different PHP systems. Each PHP system stores the **same** data in a **different** way, next image is an example :

[image]

There are tons of data already stored that way and both systems are working fine, so I can't change the PHP encoding or the databases'. One system handles the sales from the box office, the other handles the sales from the website.

**The problem** ► I need to compare the right column (`tipo_boleto_tipo`) to the left column (`tipo`) in order to get the value in another column of the left table (unseen in image), but I'm getting no results because the same values are stored different, for example, when I search for "Niños" it is not found because it was stored as "NiÃ±os" ("children" in spanish). I tried to do it via PHP by using `utf8_encode` and `utf8_decode` but it is unacceptably slow, so I think it's better to do it with SQL only. This data will be used for a unified report of sales (box office and internet) in variable periods of time and it has to compare hundreds of thousands of rows, that's why it is so slow with PHP.

**The question** ► Is there anything like `utf8_encode` or `utf8_decode` in MYSQL that allows me to match the **equivalent** values of both columns? Any other suggestion will be welcome.

Next is my current code (with no results) :

```
            DATABASE    TABLE      COLUMN
               ▼          ▼          ▼
    SELECT boleteria.tipos_boletos.genero            ◄ DESIRED COLUMN.
      FROM boleteria.tipos_boletos                   ◄ DATABASE WITH WEIRD CHARS.
INNER JOIN venta_en_linea.ventas_detalle             ◄ DATABASE WITH PROPER CHARS.
        ON venta_en_linea.ventas_detalle.tipo_boleto_tipo = boleteria.tipos_boletos.tipo
     WHERE venta_en_linea.ventas_detalle.evento_id='1'
       AND venta_en_linea.ventas_detalle.tipo_boleto_tipo = 'Niños'
```

The line `ON venta_en_linea.ventas_detalle.tipo_boleto_tipo = boleteria.tipos_boletos.tipo` is never gonna work because both values are different ("Niños" vs "NiÃ±os").

Comment: The question hasn't been closed yet, there's only one close vote. I agree, this is not a duplicate of that

Comment: Your question was never closed hence the *Possible duplicate[...]*. I've retracted my close vote and +1'd as it seems this question is unique and well presented.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez Have you tried using [`COLLATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collate.html)? Unless I've misunderstood `COLLATE` that is what you need.

Comment: @Script47, both databases and tables have the same collation = utf8_unicode_ci.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears the application which writes to the `boleteria` database is not storing correct UTF-8.  The database column character set refers to how MySQL interprets strings, but your application can still write in other character sets.

I can't tell from your example exactly what the incorrect character set is, but assuming it's Latin-1 you can convert it to latin1 (to make it "correct"), then convert it back to "actual" utf8:

```
SELECT 1
FROM tipos_boletos, ventas_detalle 
WHERE CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(tipo USING latin1) AS binary) USING utf8) 
      = tipo_boleto_tipo COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

I've seen this all too often in PHP applications that weren't written carefully from the start to use UTF-8 strings.  If you find the performance too slow and you need to convert frequently, and you don't have an opportunity to update the application writing the data incorrectly, you can add a new column and trigger to the `tipos_boletos` table and convert on the fly as records are added or edited.

Comment: It works, it works, Matt, you are the best!!! Just for future visitors of this wonderful answer, I got the error "Illegal mix of collations...", which I fixed adding `COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` at the end of the `where` (stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11770234/3298930). Thank you very very much, buddy!